# JavaFX modify font using CSS without displacing text

Tags: css, javafx, fonts

I want to easily change my application's font using CSS.

This is what I do to change it:

```
.root{
    -fx-font-family: "Courier New";
}
```

The font's are changed but all the elements are displaced (I guess it's because of the new font's size).

How can I keep the fonts with the same position and size when changing the font?

Even the textareas are narrower...

I attach two pictures with the difference.

[image: Before changing]
[image: After changing]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [mcve] please .. :) That said: you might have hit a bug here (the textfields look like they get narrower for biggen fonts and/or it might be a layout problem with the pane you are using (looks like you want them centered below the graphic and they get displaced slightly to either side - textfield to the left, label to the right)

Comment: Your nodes are probably laid out incorrectly.

Comment: My guess would be that everything that involves the `em` or `ex` units gets updated in a way undesired to you. Probably `Button`s and `TextField`s also include the text size in the calculation of the preferred size. The fact that the scene is not able to maintain the desired layout indicates a omission on your behalf to use responsive layouts though. Responsive layouts should be able to deal automatically center the elements. Try using e.g. a `VBox` to create this layout and add margins, if necessary to achieve the desired layout...